# python script using sed groups

Tags: python, regex, sed

i wrote a python script calling `sed` and have some trouble using the group operator. Here is what I have so far:

```
subprocess.check_call(["sed", "-i","-e","s/\("+str(regex)+"\)/"+str(computeSth(\1))+"/g",headers])
```

The `regex` variable simply holds a regular expression. The `computeSth` function takes as a parameter the first occurrence of the `regex` and computes the new value that should replace the `regex`. Now the problem seems to be "\1", do you have any idea how I could make this work? FYI I have no special reason to do this by calling `sed` and not hacking some lines in python except curiosity.

TIA

Comment: What do you expect `\1` to do as a Python literal?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. `sed` expects the substitution to be fixed. Do it in Python instead.

Comment: Specifically, you can do it in Python if you pass a function as the second argument to `sub`.